# Path to Deno is not correct WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, deno

I am trying to run a simple Deno project in WebStorm. I have installed **Deno** and enabled the Deno support for this project.

Also added an environment variable of the Deno bin folder with name: **DENO_INSTALL_DIR**

But while setting the run configuration it's showing an error: **Path to Deno is not correct**

Please give me a solution regarding this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it should be a full path to Deno binary. What does your run configuration look like?

Answer (score 0):

In my case bin path after default installation on ubintu is is on location: `$HOME/.deno/bin/deno`
You should have this path in your `DENO_INSTALL_DIR` environment variable, depending on your OS.